# Symfony2 Selective ESI caching

Tags: php, caching, symfony, varnish, esi

i'm using the [Liip Cache Control bundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipCacheControlBundle) to handle the caching in my project. By using this bundle you can configure the caching like this:

```
liip_cache_control:
    rules:
        - { path: /admin, controls: { private: true}, vary: [Accept-Encoding] }
        - { path: ^/_internal, controls: {private: true, max_age: 0}}
        - { path: ^/([^/]*)/live/time(.*), controls: { public: true, max_age: 1, s_maxage: 1    }, vary: [Accept-Encoding,Cookie] }
```

Now every esi (internal) route is not cached. But i now i want one internal request to be cached. Any idea how i can configure this? I cannot find which route is actually used to execute this request.

kind regards,

Daan

Comment: Did you try adding the excetion with regexp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All ESI calls are handled via an _internal route ([example from Using ESI in Symfony2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html#using-esi-in-symfony2)):

```
# app/config/routing.yml
_internal:
    resource: "@FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/routing/internal.xml"
    prefix:   /_internal
```

Documentation for [LiipCacheControlBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipCacheControlBundle) mentions how to generate internal routes:

> When using ESI, [...] To generate the corresponding _internal route,
>   inject the http_kernel into your controller and use
>   HttpKernel::generateInternalUri with the parameters as in the twig
>   render tag.

Have you tried adding appropriate rule to your liip_cache_control list? I suppose it should start with "/_internal" (try using generateInternalUri to see what's actually generated).

Comment: Thanks i found the url that was used using the generateInternalUri :)